# Identify if an Update trigger was fired by ON UPDATE CASCADE

Tags: sql-server, triggers

I have logic in my database which will block changes to a table after a 'Completed' status is set.  This is currently implemented via an AFTER UPDATE trigger.

However, I also have an ON UPDATE CASCADE foreign key for one of the fields on the table, which should be able to succeed.  Currently it is being blocked by the UPDATE trigger.

My question therefore is:
   1.  Is it possible to detect in the trigger that it is being fired by an ON UPDATE CASCADE?
   2.  Is it possible to set the trigger to not fire for an ON UPDATE CASCADE

Answer (score 0):

1. Not directly, so no
2. No.

To be honest, this is the sort of problem you get into when you don't consider all paths. There are always adminstrative / maintenance tasks that are not considered during development. So perhaps now is the time to rethink this design. If something is "completed", why can it be deleted via the cascade option? Is this part of some purge/maintenance operation? If so, that might be your key to unlocking a solution. This [search](https://www.google.com/search?q=context_info%20in%20sql%20trigger&rlz=1C1CHBF_enUS727US727&oq=tsql%20context_&aqs=chrome.4.69i57j0l5.3455j0j7&sourceid=chrome&ie=UTF-8) has suggestions for using context_info.